# Store Ints & Char in global array

Tags: c, arrays, global

I'm trying an activity online and have come across a problem. I have data about molecules and am trying to build a molecular weight calculator. The data is formatted like this:

```
   {1, 1.0079, "Hydrogen", "H"},
   {2, 4.0026, "Helium", "He"},
   {3, 6.941, "Lithium", "Li"}
```

where it has the the atomic number, the atomic weight, the name and the abbreviation.

I've used a struct:

```
struct element {
    int atomicNumber;
    double atomicWeight;
    char elementName[25];
    char abbriv[5];
};
```

and now I need to use a global array to actually store the information. I'm confused to as how I would do this as I have three different data types for each element (int, double, char). I've tried doing some research but can't find a problem similar to this. Is it possible to put this information into an array?

Also, I've only copied in 3 element descriptions above, in reality there is 109 in total so I'm having second thoughts on how to actually store large amounts of information.

The full list:

```
   {1, 1.0079, "Hydrogen", "H"},
   {2, 4.0026, "Helium", "He"},
   {3, 6.941, "Lithium", "Li"},
   {4, 9.0122, "Beryllium", "Be"},
   {5, 10.811, "Boron", "B"},
   {6, 12.0107, "Carbon", "C"},
   {7, 14.0067, "Nitrogen", "N"},
   {8, 15.9994, "Oxygen", "O"},
   {9, 18.9984, "Fluorine", "F"},
   {10, 20.1797, "Neon", "Ne"},
   {11, 22.9897, "Sodium", "Na"},
   {12, 24.305, "Magnesium", "Mg"},
   {13, 26.9815, "Aluminum", "Al"},
   {14, 28.0855, "Silicon", "Si"},
   {15, 30.9738, "Phosphorus", "P"},
   {16, 32.065, "Sulfur", "S"},
   {17, 35.453, "Chlorine", "Cl"},
   {18, 39.948, "Argon", "Ar"},
   {19, 39.0983, "Potassium", "K"},
   {20, 40.078, "Calcium", "Ca"},
   {21, 44.9559, "Scandium", "Sc"},
   {22, 47.867, "Titanium", "Ti"},
   {23, 50.9415, "Vanadium", "V"},
   {24, 51.9961, "Chromium", "Cr"},
   {25, 54.938, "Manganese", "Mn"},
   {26, 55.845, "Iron", "Fe"},
   {27, 58.9332, "Cobalt", "Co"},
   {28, 58.6934, "Nickel", "Ni"},
   {29, 63.546, "Copper", "Cu"},
   {30, 65.39, "Zinc", "Zn"},
   {31, 69.723, "Gallium", "Ga"},
   {32, 72.64, "Germanium", "Ge"},
   {33, 74.9216, "Arsenic", "As"},
   {34, 78.96, "Selenium", "Se"},
   {35, 79.904, "Bromine", "Br"},
   {36, 83.8, "Krypton", "Kr"},
   {37, 85.4678, "Rubidium", "Rb"},
   {38, 87.62, "Strontium", "Sr"},
   {39, 88.9059, "Yttrium", "Y"},
   {40, 91.224, "Zirconium", "Zr"},
   {41, 92.9064, "Niobium", "Nb"},
   {42, 95.94, "Molybdenum", "Mo"},
   {43, 98, "Technetium", "Tc"},
   {44, 101.07, "Ruthenium", "Ru"},
   {45, 102.9055, "Rhodium", "Rh"},
   {46, 106.42, "Palladium", "Pd"},
   {47, 107.8682, "Silver", "Ag"},
   {48, 112.411, "Cadmium", "Cd"},
   {49, 114.818, "Indium", "In"},
   {50, 118.71, "Tin", "Sn"},
   {51, 121.76, "Antimony", "Sb"},
   {52, 127.6, "Tellurium", "Te"},
   {53, 126.9045, "Iodine", "I"},
   {54, 131.293, "Xenon", "Xe"},
   {55, 132.9055, "Cesium", "Cs"},
   {56, 137.327, "Barium", "Ba"},
   {57, 138.9055, "Lanthanum", "La"},
   {58, 140.116, "Cerium", "Ce"},
   {59, 140.9077, "Praseodymium", "Pr"},
   {60, 144.24, "Neodymium", "Nd"},
   {61, 145, "Promethium", "Pm"},
   {62, 150.36, "Samarium", "Sm"},
   {63, 151.964, "Europium", "Eu"},
   {64, 157.25, "Gadolinium", "Gd"},
   {65, 158.9253, "Terbium", "Tb"},
   {66, 162.5, "Dysprosium", "Dy"},
   {67, 164.9303, "Holmium", "Ho"},
   {68, 167.259, "Erbium", "Er"},
   {69, 168.9342, "Thulium", "Tm"},
   {70, 173.04, "Ytterbium", "Yb"},
   {71, 174.967, "Lutetium", "Lu"},
   {72, 178.49, "Hafnium", "Hf"},
   {73, 180.9479, "Tantalum", "Ta"},
   {74, 183.84, "Tungsten", "W"},
   {75, 186.207, "Rhenium", "Re"},
   {76, 190.23, "Osmium", "Os"},
   {77, 192.217, "Iridium", "Ir"},
   {78, 195.078, "Platinum", "Pt"},
   {79, 196.9665, "Gold", "Au"},
   {80, 200.59, "Mercury", "Hg"},
   {81, 204.3833, "Thallium", "Tl"},
   {82, 207.2, "Lead", "Pb"},
   {83, 208.9804, "Bismuth", "Bi"},
   {84, 209, "Polonium", "Po"},
   {85, 210, "Astatine", "At"},
   {86, 222, "Radon", "Rn"},
   {87, 223, "Francium", "Fr"},
   {88, 226, "Radium", "Ra"},
   {89, 227, "Actinium", "Ac"},
   {90, 232.0381, "Thorium", "Th"},
   {91, 231.0359, "Protactinium", "Pa"},
   {92, 238.0289, "Uranium", "U"},
   {93, 237, "Neptunium", "Np"},
   {94, 244, "Plutonium", "Pu"},
   {95, 243, "Americium", "Am"},
   {96, 247, "Curium", "Cm"},
   {97, 247, "Berkelium", "Bk"},
   {98, 251, "Californium", "Cf"},
   {99, 252, "Einsteinium", "Es"},
   {100, 257, "Fermium", "Fm"},
   {101, 258, "Mendelevium", "Md"},
   {102, 259, "Nobelium", "No"},
   {103, 262, "Lawrencium", "Lr"},
   {104, 261, "Rutherfordium", "Rf"},
   {105, 262, "Dubnium", "Db"},
   {106, 266, "Seaborgium", "Sg"},
   {107, 264, "Bohrium", "Bh"},
   {108, 277, "Hassium", "Hs"},
   {109, 268, "Meitnerium", "Mt"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are on the right track, now you can create an array of `struct` variables and assign all those to it at once and access it via a loop.

Something like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define NUM_OF_ELEMENTS 109

struct element {
    int atomicNumber;
    double atomicWeight;
    char elementName[25];
    char abbriv[5];
};

struct element elements[NUM_OF_ELEMENTS]={
   {1, 1.0079, "Hydrogen", "H"},
   {2, 4.0026, "Helium", "He"},
   {3, 6.941, "Lithium", "Li"},
   {4, 9.0122, "Beryllium", "Be"},
   {5, 10.811, "Boron", "B"},
   {6, 12.0107, "Carbon", "C"},
   {7, 14.0067, "Nitrogen", "N"},
   {8, 15.9994, "Oxygen", "O"},
   {9, 18.9984, "Fluorine", "F"},
   {10, 20.1797, "Neon", "Ne"},
   {11, 22.9897, "Sodium", "Na"},
   {12, 24.305, "Magnesium", "Mg"},
   {13, 26.9815, "Aluminum", "Al"},
   {14, 28.0855, "Silicon", "Si"},
   {15, 30.9738, "Phosphorus", "P"},
   {16, 32.065, "Sulfur", "S"},
   {17, 35.453, "Chlorine", "Cl"},
   {18, 39.948, "Argon", "Ar"},
   {19, 39.0983, "Potassium", "K"},
   {20, 40.078, "Calcium", "Ca"},
   {21, 44.9559, "Scandium", "Sc"},
   {22, 47.867, "Titanium", "Ti"},
   {23, 50.9415, "Vanadium", "V"},
   {24, 51.9961, "Chromium", "Cr"},
   {25, 54.938, "Manganese", "Mn"},
   {26, 55.845, "Iron", "Fe"},
   {27, 58.9332, "Cobalt", "Co"},
   {28, 58.6934, "Nickel", "Ni"},
   {29, 63.546, "Copper", "Cu"},
   {30, 65.39, "Zinc", "Zn"},
   {31, 69.723, "Gallium", "Ga"},
   {32, 72.64, "Germanium", "Ge"},
   {33, 74.9216, "Arsenic", "As"},
   {34, 78.96, "Selenium", "Se"},
   {35, 79.904, "Bromine", "Br"},
   {36, 83.8, "Krypton", "Kr"},
   {37, 85.4678, "Rubidium", "Rb"},
   {38, 87.62, "Strontium", "Sr"},
   {39, 88.9059, "Yttrium", "Y"},
   {40, 91.224, "Zirconium", "Zr"},
   {41, 92.9064, "Niobium", "Nb"},
   {42, 95.94, "Molybdenum", "Mo"},
   {43, 98, "Technetium", "Tc"},
   {44, 101.07, "Ruthenium", "Ru"},
   {45, 102.9055, "Rhodium", "Rh"},
   {46, 106.42, "Palladium", "Pd"},
   {47, 107.8682, "Silver", "Ag"},
   {48, 112.411, "Cadmium", "Cd"},
   {49, 114.818, "Indium", "In"},
   {50, 118.71, "Tin", "Sn"},
   {51, 121.76, "Antimony", "Sb"},
   {52, 127.6, "Tellurium", "Te"},
   {53, 126.9045, "Iodine", "I"},
   {54, 131.293, "Xenon", "Xe"},
   {55, 132.9055, "Cesium", "Cs"},
   {56, 137.327, "Barium", "Ba"},
   {57, 138.9055, "Lanthanum", "La"},
   {58, 140.116, "Cerium", "Ce"},
   {59, 140.9077, "Praseodymium", "Pr"},
   {60, 144.24, "Neodymium", "Nd"},
   {61, 145, "Promethium", "Pm"},
   {62, 150.36, "Samarium", "Sm"},
   {63, 151.964, "Europium", "Eu"},
   {64, 157.25, "Gadolinium", "Gd"},
   {65, 158.9253, "Terbium", "Tb"},
   {66, 162.5, "Dysprosium", "Dy"},
   {67, 164.9303, "Holmium", "Ho"},
   {68, 167.259, "Erbium", "Er"},
   {69, 168.9342, "Thulium", "Tm"},
   {70, 173.04, "Ytterbium", "Yb"},
   {71, 174.967, "Lutetium", "Lu"},
   {72, 178.49, "Hafnium", "Hf"},
   {73, 180.9479, "Tantalum", "Ta"},
   {74, 183.84, "Tungsten", "W"},
   {75, 186.207, "Rhenium", "Re"},
   {76, 190.23, "Osmium", "Os"},
   {77, 192.217, "Iridium", "Ir"},
   {78, 195.078, "Platinum", "Pt"},
   {79, 196.9665, "Gold", "Au"},
   {80, 200.59, "Mercury", "Hg"},
   {81, 204.3833, "Thallium", "Tl"},
   {82, 207.2, "Lead", "Pb"},
   {83, 208.9804, "Bismuth", "Bi"},
   {84, 209, "Polonium", "Po"},
   {85, 210, "Astatine", "At"},
   {86, 222, "Radon", "Rn"},
   {87, 223, "Francium", "Fr"},
   {88, 226, "Radium", "Ra"},
   {89, 227, "Actinium", "Ac"},
   {90, 232.0381, "Thorium", "Th"},
   {91, 231.0359, "Protactinium", "Pa"},
   {92, 238.0289, "Uranium", "U"},
   {93, 237, "Neptunium", "Np"},
   {94, 244, "Plutonium", "Pu"},
   {95, 243, "Americium", "Am"},
   {96, 247, "Curium", "Cm"},
   {97, 247, "Berkelium", "Bk"},
   {98, 251, "Californium", "Cf"},
   {99, 252, "Einsteinium", "Es"},
   {100, 257, "Fermium", "Fm"},
   {101, 258, "Mendelevium", "Md"},
   {102, 259, "Nobelium", "No"},
   {103, 262, "Lawrencium", "Lr"},
   {104, 261, "Rutherfordium", "Rf"},
   {105, 262, "Dubnium", "Db"},
   {106, 266, "Seaborgium", "Sg"},
   {107, 264, "Bohrium", "Bh"},
   {108, 277, "Hassium", "Hs"},
   {109, 268, "Meitnerium", "Mt"}
};

void main()
{
    int i;

    printf("%13s\t%13s\t%25s\t%s\n", "Atomic Number", "Atomic Weight", "Element Name", "Abbrevation");
    for(i = 0; i < NUM_OF_ELEMENTS; i++)
        printf("%13d\t%13.2lf\t%25s\t%5s\n", elements[i].atomicNumber,
            elements[i].atomicWeight,
            elements[i].elementName,
            elements[i].abbriv);
}
```

And here is the output:

```
$ gcc prgm.c 
$ ./a.out 
Atomic Number   Atomic Weight                Element Name   Abbrevation
            1            1.01                    Hydrogen       H
            2            4.00                      Helium      He
            3            6.94                     Lithium      Li
            4            9.01                   Beryllium      Be
            5           10.81                       Boron       B
            6           12.01                      Carbon       C
            7           14.01                    Nitrogen       N
            8           16.00                      Oxygen       O
            9           19.00                    Fluorine       F
           10           20.18                        Neon      Ne
           11           22.99                      Sodium      Na
           12           24.30                   Magnesium      Mg
           13           26.98                    Aluminum      Al
           14           28.09                     Silicon      Si
           15           30.97                  Phosphorus       P
           16           32.06                      Sulfur       S
           17           35.45                    Chlorine      Cl
           18           39.95                       Argon      Ar
           19           39.10                   Potassium       K
           20           40.08                     Calcium      Ca
           21           44.96                    Scandium      Sc
           22           47.87                    Titanium      Ti
           23           50.94                    Vanadium       V
           24           52.00                    Chromium      Cr
           25           54.94                   Manganese      Mn
           26           55.84                        Iron      Fe
           27           58.93                      Cobalt      Co
           28           58.69                      Nickel      Ni
           29           63.55                      Copper      Cu
           30           65.39                        Zinc      Zn
           31           69.72                     Gallium      Ga
           32           72.64                   Germanium      Ge
           33           74.92                     Arsenic      As
           34           78.96                    Selenium      Se
           35           79.90                     Bromine      Br
           36           83.80                     Krypton      Kr
           37           85.47                    Rubidium      Rb
           38           87.62                   Strontium      Sr
           39           88.91                     Yttrium       Y
           40           91.22                   Zirconium      Zr
           41           92.91                     Niobium      Nb
           42           95.94                  Molybdenum      Mo
           43           98.00                  Technetium      Tc
           44          101.07                   Ruthenium      Ru
           45          102.91                     Rhodium      Rh
           46          106.42                   Palladium      Pd
           47          107.87                      Silver      Ag
           48          112.41                     Cadmium      Cd
           49          114.82                      Indium      In
           50          118.71                         Tin      Sn
           51          121.76                    Antimony      Sb
           52          127.60                   Tellurium      Te
           53          126.90                      Iodine       I
           54          131.29                       Xenon      Xe
           55          132.91                      Cesium      Cs
           56          137.33                      Barium      Ba
           57          138.91                   Lanthanum      La
           58          140.12                      Cerium      Ce
           59          140.91                Praseodymium      Pr
           60          144.24                   Neodymium      Nd
           61          145.00                  Promethium      Pm
           62          150.36                    Samarium      Sm
           63          151.96                    Europium      Eu
           64          157.25                  Gadolinium      Gd
           65          158.93                     Terbium      Tb
           66          162.50                  Dysprosium      Dy
           67          164.93                     Holmium      Ho
           68          167.26                      Erbium      Er
           69          168.93                     Thulium      Tm
           70          173.04                   Ytterbium      Yb
           71          174.97                    Lutetium      Lu
           72          178.49                     Hafnium      Hf
           73          180.95                    Tantalum      Ta
           74          183.84                    Tungsten       W
           75          186.21                     Rhenium      Re
           76          190.23                      Osmium      Os
           77          192.22                     Iridium      Ir
           78          195.08                    Platinum      Pt
           79          196.97                        Gold      Au
           80          200.59                     Mercury      Hg
           81          204.38                    Thallium      Tl
           82          207.20                        Lead      Pb
           83          208.98                     Bismuth      Bi
           84          209.00                    Polonium      Po
           85          210.00                    Astatine      At
           86          222.00                       Radon      Rn
           87          223.00                    Francium      Fr
           88          226.00                      Radium      Ra
           89          227.00                    Actinium      Ac
           90          232.04                     Thorium      Th
           91          231.04                Protactinium      Pa
           92          238.03                     Uranium       U
           93          237.00                   Neptunium      Np
           94          244.00                   Plutonium      Pu
           95          243.00                   Americium      Am
           96          247.00                      Curium      Cm
           97          247.00                   Berkelium      Bk
           98          251.00                 Californium      Cf
           99          252.00                 Einsteinium      Es
          100          257.00                     Fermium      Fm
          101          258.00                 Mendelevium      Md
          102          259.00                    Nobelium      No
          103          262.00                  Lawrencium      Lr
          104          261.00               Rutherfordium      Rf
          105          262.00                     Dubnium      Db
          106          266.00                  Seaborgium      Sg
          107          264.00                     Bohrium      Bh
          108          277.00                     Hassium      Hs
          109          268.00                  Meitnerium      Mt
$
```

Comment: You also don't need to set the array's size when you declare it like this, you can have it set to the number of structs passed by going struct element elements[]= { ... };    of course you can still explicitly set the array's size if you like, if you want to make sure its padded to a certain size.

Comment: @matt or if he wants to make sure the correct number of elements are present, also the `sizeof` operator can be applied if you want to determine the size of the array like this `struct element elements[] = {...};` then `sizeof(elements) / sizeof(elements[0])` would give the number of elements in the array.

Comment: Making the array `const` is not a bad idea too.

Comment: You have something against the heavier elements starting at `Darmstadtium`?

Comment: Hey thank you for this. Is there any information on this I can read up on? Like how does it know atomicNumber is equal to the to the first element (0) in the array and atomicWeight is element 1?, etc... Does it depend on how you declare the variables in the struct element before the array?

Comment: yep, pretty sure it just goes by their order of declaration in the struct (which means you need to be careful not to reorder them). *If* you were using C++, A way around not worrying about the order is to create a constructor in your struct that allows you to pass in the values in an order of your choosing independent of the order the members are declared.   Then you would just replace {1, 1.0079, "Hydrogen", "H"},  with element(1, 1.0079, "Hydrogen", "H"),    But you can't do that in plain C.

Comment: @EbonyDoe its a combination of arrays and structures, some tutorials can be found at: http://www-ee.eng.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap12/section2.1.2.html, [here](http://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-array/) and [here](http://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-array-of-structures/)

Comment: Just as a side-note: when dealing with large const arrays, it is generally good practice to do `struct element elements[] = ...` and then `_Static_assert(sizeof(elements)/sizeof(*elements) == NUM_OF_ELEMENTS, "Wrong number of elements!");`. Otherwise the compiler can't tell if there are too few elements.

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking to do is creating an array of structs.

Eg.

```
struct elements myArray[108];
myArray[0].atomicNumber = 1;
myArray[0].atomicWeight = 1.0079;
myArray[0].elementName = "Hydrogen";
myArray[0].abbriv = "H";
```

Obviously there are a lot of elements in your table, so you can easily automate this process with a loop.